# Atlassian Connect Addon for Autocomplete Field

Tags: autocomplete, field, jira, atlassian-connect

I was wondering if its possible to CHANGE text field to act like autocomplete using the Atlassian connect addons?(im using JIRA Cloud). I mean IS it possible to be done with addon written on Javascript or Node JS?

Answer (score 1):

No, Cloud add-ons are sandboxed and the access they get to the underlying JIRA instance is very tightly regulated. You cannot modify the UI in any way.